# Communicating with ARIN Whois server

Tags: telnet, whois

Connecting to the ARIN Whois server via telnet works like so:

> telnet whois.arin.net 43

Once connected, getting information about an IP address is equally trivial:

> n 119.194.24.35

A lot of information is shown about this specific IP including Country, etc. However, with the following IP address, I get very little information:

> n 216.172.138.91

Why does this query show me so little information unlike the first one? How do I attain the same level of detail about an IP as the first when I get minimal answers such as this?

Note: I am not interested in any utility that will show me this information. I am only interested in more information about manual retrieval using telnet as my only interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [ARIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Registry_for_Internet_Numbers) is (mostly) only authoritative for North America. There are also other [RIRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry) (Regional Internet Registries): [RIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPE) (Europe), [APNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNIC) (Asia-Pacic), [AfriNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFRINIC) (Africa), [LACNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LACNIC) (Latin America), and even more whois servers of lower level (Korean KrNIC in your case)

If you want to program it yourself, you'll have to know which server to ask, see for example [here](https://github.com/rfc1036/whois/blob/master/ip_del_list). Or ask *whois.iana.org*

But to answer your question directly - because ARIN has TWO (more and less specific delegations for that IP), and so it defaults to summary and not details. To display details when more than one match is found on ARIN, you have to use "+" modifier, for example:

> telnet whois.arin.net whois
>
> n + 216.172.138.91

This would display lots of info

Comment: You would also be well served by following referrals, if you can devise some means of doing so.